# Cassandra cql3 PHP support

Tags: php, cassandra, cql3

I know that there is no official driver to use Cassandra cql3 with PHP yet. I learned about the map, list and set features in cql3 and would really love to use it on my application. Is there anyway to make cql3 queries work in PHP (for example running cql3 queries in Java/C# and return the result to PHP or run the query as shell command using exec() in PHP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[YACassandraPDO](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO) should do the trick. It is afaik the only actively maintained PHP client for cassandra.

According to the doc, YACassandraPDO supports collection data types.

> Added support for float numbers, decimals
>   Added support for collections (**map, set, list**)

Answer (score 1):

[php-cassandra-binary](http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/) uses Cassandra's binary protocol instead of the deprecated thrift protocol. It supports all of Cassandra's types.